# Method for Comparing two different rates?

Tags: time-series, inference, biostatistics

The first rate is deaths from opioids yearly.
The second rate is hospitalization rate from opioids. Both of these rates span 25 years.

I am just trying to see if the hospitalization rates follow the same pattern as death rates (statistically). Not just by looking at a graph.

I know these rates are technically not the same thing, so I am not sure how to compare them. These rates are from the same area and over the same time period.